# How to limit the region in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I create a project in google cloud and specify a region, it does not limit the resources within that project to the specified region. When I create, say an image within that project, it spins up resources (most of which are temporary cloud build resources) all over the place. Is there a way for me to limit the creation of resources to a specific region. For reference the command is `gcloud compute images import` and it does not have the `--region` flag.

Comment: The command `gcloud compute images import` supports the `--storage-location` command flag. You can specify either a region or a multi-region location. Combine that with @guillaume-blaquiere answer and I think you can achieve your goals. AFAIK all commands affected by location constraints support specifying the region where data is stored.

Comment: That did not work. That option does not limit the command to spin up resources within a region.

Comment: Which part did not work? I commented on the storage location, not where you can launch instances. Reread my comment. Part of your question asked about `--region`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use organization policy to restrict the usable regions. See more in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/defining-locations)

Comment: You nailed it. Because of the constraint, when you execute those commands it fails. Reason the command fails is it tries to create those temporary resources all over the place (dont know how Google decides which location to setup the resources in but I suppose it selects the cheapest region). Setting up resources in any location fails because of the constraint.
Worth pointing out that when it fails, it does not state the constraint as the reason for the failure. Makes troubleshooting extremely tricky.
Back to my question, how do we limit these commands to a particular region ?

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but should point out that once I remove the constraint the command runs to completion.

Comment: OK, so, can you detail which services you want to limit. Indeed, according to the type of service, you sometimes need to perform additional things and configuration to make it working with the region constraint policy. On the other hand, if you only want a default region with the gcloud CLI, there are configuration default values to set to achieve that.

Comment: The command I am trying to run is "gcloud compute images import" ; what services that might spin up in the background is really hard for me to figure out.